# How do I properly display emoji in Neovim?

Tags: neovim

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 and I have neovim (I think I have the latest version) v0.6.1.

When I use an emoji in my code, like this coral:

[image]

And then I switch buffers. I see an artifact (in this case the letter 'l') from the width mismatch of that emoji (I think this is what that hanging 'l' is anyway).

[image]

I would love to understand how to fix this, or how to upgrade my neovim if I'm just a few versions behind.

I've tried `sudo apt install neovim` and it says I'm on the latest.

**Update**

Here's the code with the emoji:

```
    div.connect-others
      h2 Help Us  Save Coral
```

In Gnome terminal you can tell it to treat special characters as narrow or wide, and regardless of which you do, you end up with mismatches that leave behind artifacts.

In Neovim that's the last character on the line showing in the next buffers as you switch buffers, if you have 'narrow' as the setting in Gnome Terminal. If you have 'wide' set, it'll push whole lines down and leave much more in those "artifacts."

Here's the issue in the Neovim Github: https://github.com/wez/wezterm/issues/1231

Comment: The latest stable of Neovim is 0.8.2. But I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Your screenshots are confusing me. Is the first screenshot a Neovim screenshot? Is the second screenshot displaying the same buffer (the content, line number, neovim settings seems different). It would help if you could give us more context.

Comment: Thanks! I have to figure out how to upgrade. I guess the PPA is behind? They are both screenshots of the same location on my screen, but two different buffers. The hanging 'l' is an artifact from the first buffer (screenshot) spilling over into the second.

Comment: Thanks I understand now :-)

Comment: Is your problem solved by upgrading?

Comment: Upgraded!! : ) But doesn't solve the problem. Upgraded to 0.7.2 by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll try to reproduce the problem on Windows but at first glance it look like a bug in Neovim. Could you share your text with the Coral character or give its Unicode?

Comment: I can share the text. I doubt it would reproduce on Windows. But worth a shot : )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142389/discussion-between-vivian-de-smedt-and-costa-michailidis).